# yii1.1 how to use event from external component?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

i have event on action "onBeforeSave()" for my Model, and i use it from internal class with $this and it work correctly,
may question is :how to change its behavior to use form external component?
,because i want to connect it with external project

```
     <?php
class Hello extends CApplicationComponent
{
    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        Member::model()->onBeforeSave = function(){
            echo 'helllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllo';
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: the behavior of event in yii is not allow to use event from external component like before how to change it to use the previous code